# Cerrar sesiones ActiveMQ C#

Tags: c#, activemq

He creado una aplicación de consola en C# que realiza validaciones en SQL y si encuentra diferencias las envia por un topico al ActiveMQ, ahora el problema radica en que me dicen algunos compañeros de TI, que ** la aplicación esta bloqueando el ActiveMQ porque supera el número de conexiones(250) al parecer cada que se conecta crea una nueva sesión.**

sobra decir que soy nuevo usando el activeMQ, esta es la primera aplicación que hago donde consumo un topico.
codigo utilizado.

````
Uri uri = new Uri("failover: (tcp://IP1:61617,tcp://IP2:61617)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=1&amp;initialReconnectDelay=1");
                IConnectionFactory iconnfactory = new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory(uri);
                IConnection conn = iconnfactory.CreateConnection();
                conn.Start();
                ISession session = conn.CreateSession();
                IMessageProducer prod = session.CreateProducer(new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Commands.ActiveMQTopic(Topic));
                ITextMessage msg = prod.CreateTextMessage();
                msg.Text = "<?xml version=" + '\u0022' + "1.0" + '\u0022' + " encoding=" + '\u0022' + "UTF-8" + '\u0022' + " standalone=" + '\u0022' + "yes" +
                                        '\u0022' + " ?><Elements><Element Type = " + '\u0022' + "34" + '\u0022' + " Id=" + '\u0022' + j + '\u0022' + " State=" + '\u0022' + e + '\u0022' + " ></Element></Elements> ";
                msg.NMSDeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.Persistent;
                prod.Send(msg);
                Console.WriteLine(prod.ToString());
                prod.Close();
                session.Close();
                conn.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Se actualizan los estados"); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucinado evitando iniciar más sesiones, solo inicio sesión una vez y en las conexiones del activeMQ solo se ve 1.
el codigo quedo de esta manera.

´´´

```
string Topic = "T_ESTADO_SISTEMA";
                if (Contador == 0)
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("failover:(tcp://IP1:61617,tcp://IP2:61617)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=1&amp;initialReconnectDelay=1");
                    IConnectionFactory iconnfactory = new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory(uri);
                    conn = iconnfactory.CreateConnection();
                    conn.Start();
                    session = conn.CreateSession();
                    prod = session.CreateProducer(new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Commands.ActiveMQTopic(Topic));
                    Contador = 1; 
                }
                int e = 1;
                 ITextMessage msg = prod.CreateTextMessage();
                 msg.Text = "<?xml version=" + '\u0022' + "1.0" + '\u0022' + " encoding=" + '\u0022' + "UTF-8" + '\u0022' + " standalone=" + '\u0022' + "yes" +
                                        '\u0022' + " ?><Elements><Element Type = " + '\u0022' + "34" + '\u0022' + " Id=" + '\u0022' + j + '\u0022' + " State=" + '\u0022' + e + '\u0022' + " ></Element></Elements> ";
                msg.NMSDeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.NonPersistent;
                prod.Send(msg);
```